# Изменить txt при нажатии на Enter

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Enter у меня в `textarea` с `id = 'txt'`, менялся текст при условии того, что я написал что-то?

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
if (txt == '/help') {
    txt.innerHTML = 'что либо';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что после нажатия enter к value добавляется символ перевода строки:

```js
const text = document.getElementById('txt');

text.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if(text.value == '/help\n' && event.keyCode == 13) {
  text.value = 'что либо';
 }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

---

**upd**

Насчёт второго хелпа - всё по той же логике (не забываем про переносы строк):

```js
const text = document.getElementById('txt');

text.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if(text.value == '/help\n' && event.keyCode == 13) {
  text.value = 'что либо';
 }
  else if(text.value == 'что либо\n/help2\n' && event.keyCode == 13) {
     text.value = 'что либо\nи что-то другое ещё';
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

Comment: Теперь помогло, спасибо большое!

Comment: А можно ещё вопрос, я вот добавляю ещё условие, но что-то не получается, я добавляю условие после первого условия, дописываю else if, может я то-то не так делаю?

Comment: @НикитаКраснобаев, так напишите, какое именно условие и какой ожидается результат (что должно произойти при наступлении условия)

Comment: я хочу добавить текст после первого условия, допустим я написал /help, мне что-то вывелось, а после этого когда я добавлю другую команду, допустим /help 2, нужно чтобы выводился ещё один текст ниже

Comment: @НикитаКраснобаев, я добавил примерный вариант в ответ. Там самое главное - правильно проверять value (то есть понимать, что именно и в каком виде Вы хотите видеть в textarea в конечном итоге)

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень сильно помогли!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю автору познакомится с событиями в js, а также пример кода который типо по идеи поможет с данной проблемой

```
$('#txt').on('keydown', => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      if ($('#txt').val() === '/help') {
    $('#txt').html('Что либо')
  }
})
```

Comment: всё равно не помогает, может мне надо добавить кнопку, и чтобы создать событие при котором когда я нажимаю на enter, воспроизводилось нажатие кнопки, которая в своё время меняет текст?